# How do I preserve transparency in ggplot2?

Tags: r

I love the plots that ggplot generates. However, it is still somewhat cumbersome to get publication quality plots directly. I usually have to do some post processing in Illustrator (i.e. changing fonts, numbering figures etc). While I could save as tiff or png, eps is best for manipulating figures in Illustrator (I can ungroup objects, move the legend/text etc).

When I save a ggplot object with some transparency (either in points or a smoother) I get this error:

```
Warning message:
In grid.Call.graphics("L_points", x$x, x$y, x$pch, x$size) :
  semi-transparency is not supported on this device: reported only once per page
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Below also an easily solution to export in an editable vector-based format directly to Powerpoint, where you can easily fix minor formatting issues, and with full preservation of transparency. See if that suits you...

Comment: I think my answer below more accurately and fully answers your question, so you might like to check that one as the correct answer - well, see what you think...

Comment: Added a solution below using the new export package - I think that one should be flagged as the correct answer in fact...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

R's eps "device" doesn't support partial transparency, but, if I remember correctly, its PDF device does.  Illustrator ought to be able to read PDFs with equal facility to EPSes, or if not, try converting them after generation with `pdftops` (*not* `pdf2ps`, they are totally different programs and pdf2ps's output is ... inferior).

Note that R doesn't try to optimize its PDF output *at all*, so even if you do get a plot that needs no postproduction, you will want to run it through a compression utility like `qpdf` at the very least.

Comment: Thanks! For those of you on OSX, <a href="http://tex.aanhet.net/epspdf/#install">here</a> is an easy tool to convert from pdf to eps.

Comment: Er... this doesn't work. Unless I'm missing an option, if I try `pdftops -eps graph.pdf graph.eps`, where graph has semi-transparent vector lines, then those parts of the graph will be rasterised in the EPS. This is pretty much useless (I may as well convert to jpeg). http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24287/13192 indicates that postscript doesn't support semi-transparency at all...

Comment: @naught101 Huh, I thought that had been added to postscript at some point.  I don't know what your situation is, but I would try to eliminate the use of EPS files altogether -- pdfTeX for instance can slurp in PDF-format graphics just fine (in fact this is *easier* than getting it to eat EPSes).

Comment: Zack: I know. It works for me. I can't help that the journal I'm submitting to is technologically backward though.

Comment: @naught101 Yeah, you may be up a creek, sorry.

Answer (score 47):

This works:

```
ggsave("filename.eps", device=cairo_ps)
```

Comment: This does work. Why was it downvoted without comment?

Comment: I agree--this is a great solution that I plan to use frequently.

Comment: As pointed out here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31380625/4598520 cairo_ps  automatically rasterizes transparency, but does so at low resolution  (72 dpi)

Comment: You can also add the argument fallback_resolution to control the resolution at which semi-transparent areas are rasterized (this was introduced in a recent R update), e.g. you can now use ggsave("filename.eps", device=cairo_ps, fallback_resolution = 600)

Comment: I get an unused argument error when I try to add the fallback_resolution? @TomWenseleers

Comment: Well for me this works though: cairo_ps(file = "test.eps",onefile = FALSE,fallback_resolution=600)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))
dev.off()

Comment: And I don't get an error when I try ggsave("filename.eps", device=cairo_ps, fallback_resolution=600) either... I'm working under Windows, and you?

Comment: This is under R 3.3.3 - I know it's been introduced relatively recently though, so is the R version you are using a recent one?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issues with using the `postscript` function. I found that `cairo_ps` from the `grDevices` package does support transparency (at least in Ubuntu 10.04 with R version 2.10.1). Usage would be:

```
cairo_ps(filename='filename.eps', width=7, height=7)
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

Comment: You can also add the argument fallback_resolution to control the resolution at which semi-transparent areas are rasterized (this was introduced in a recent R update) (e.g. fallback_resolution=600 for 600 dpi)

Comment: Upvote to this solution as it provides a wide range of functionality for the problem. In my case I was using grid.arrange for multiple plots and the other solutions would not have worked

Answer (score 6):

You could also try exporting as SVG via the svg device. Not sure if Illustrator can read SVG, but Inkscape can, and it's open source :) I've done some good things with R output to SVG in Inkscape, and the groupings are preserved as with EPS. Can't be 100% sure it handles opacity but I'm sure its in the SVG standard.

Comment: SVG works too although it created weird, large, semitransparent letters in the background. There was a really big O,X,Y in the background. But I was able to remove those. So this is another option that allows for skipping the conversion. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The EPS format in principle does not support semi-transparency - if you want semi-transparency and be able to edit in Illustrator or Inkscape you would better export to SVG or PDF. If you are really tied to the EPS format you could use the `cairo` device though, and specify at what resolution semi-transparent objects need to be rasterized (only the non-semitransparent elements stay as vector format then though, semi-transparant areas are rasterized to bitmap). The syntax to do this is:

```
cairo_ps(file = "test.eps", onefile = FALSE, fallback_resolution = 600)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))
dev.off()
```

or

```
ggsave("filename.eps", device=cairo_ps, fallback_resolution = 600)
```

An alternative option is to export to MS Office Powerpoint in vector format, and do any layout editing there. This can be done easily using my new `export` package,
see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and for demo
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

Typical syntax is very easy, e.g.:

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="ggplot2_plot.pptx", width=6, height=5)
```

This results in a fully editable, high quality Powerpoint graph in native Office vector-based  DrawingML format, with full support for transparency. In there you can easily fix minor formatting issues, and export to a high quality PDF by printing to PDF.

You can also use it to export to Word, Excel, Latex or HTML and you can also use it to export statistical output of various R stats objects.

It also has a `graph2eps(file="plot.eps", width=6, height=5, fallback_resolution=600)` function to export to eps with rasterizing of semi-transparent areas...

Answer (score -3):

I found an easy way to do so.

Use "zoom" in R plot and click right mouse to copy the picture. You can get a plot with shadow.