# Error using Arial in .eps figure with extrafont package

Tags: r, fonts, ggplot2, eps

I'm using ggplot2 in R to generate figures for a publication in which all figures need to be .eps format and all fonts needs to be Arial. I've been following [this guide](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/09/09/preparing-figures-for-plos-one-with-r/) to doing this using the extrafont package. As I understand it, the line `loadfonts(device = "postscript")` should register all of the fonts I imported (which includes Arial) with the postscript device. But when I run my code and try to save my figure using this code:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + theme_minimal(base_family = "Arial")
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device = "postscript")
ggsave(filename = "myfile.eps")
```

I still get this error:

> Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, 
>   :    family 'Arial' not included in postscript() device

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are on a Windows OS, you can alternatively create the graph using the [showtext](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/showtext/index.html) package.

```
library(showtext)
## add the Arial font
font.add("Arial", regular = "arial.ttf",
    bold = "arialbd.ttf", italic = "ariali.ttf", bolditalic = "arialbi.ttf")

setEPS()
postscript("some_graph.eps")
showtext.begin() ## call this function after opening a device

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
    theme_minimal(base_family = "Arial")

dev.off()
```

The drawback is that you cannot use the `ggsave()` function, but instead call the device function by yourself.

For the usage of the `showtext` package, a README is given at https://github.com/yixuan/showtext.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm running Linux Mint.

Comment: Then you just need to change "arial.ttf" to the location of your Arial font file. Bold, italic and bold-italic font faces can be set accordingly, but are not necessary.

Comment: Excellent! That gave me a transparency error, but I solved it by using cairo_ps, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001316/how-do-i-preserve-transparency-in-ggplot2

Comment: Also, I didn't actually have to specify a different path to my Arial font file.

Comment: `showtext` will try to search some standard font directories (`?font.paths()`). If the file is within those directories, only the filename of the font is needed, not necessarily the whole path.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled over this problem as well when using the `extrafonts` package with `ggsave()` for `eps`-files. I know this thread is old, but maybe my workaround may help others in the future. :)

R isn’t good at font embedding. However, R has included the Cairo graphics library in the past (therefore you *don’t* need to install the Cairo package anymore!), which is able to handle the embedding. To save an `.eps` using the Cairo graphics library just use `cairo_ps` as `device`:

```
ggsave(filename="Fig1.eps", plot = last_plot(), device = cairo_ps)
```

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, I also had trouble using extrafont with Arial (but on Windows), and it turned out there were multiple causes.

The errors I received were: `Error in title(...) : metric information not available for this device`, `In title(...) : font metrics unknown for character 0x4d` and `font width unknown`.

It turns out that extrafont requires ghostscript, which is not at all clear from these error messages. In fact, I had ghostscript installed, but (at least in my case) it also had to be registered in the Path environment variable, as described [here](http://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2009-April/008314.html) (substitute your version number).

Even with that in place, it appears that it is not the font names listed in `names(postscriptFonts())` and `fonttable()` that can be used. `Arial` and `Times New Roman` (or `TimesNewRoman` or `TimesNewRomanPSMT`) don't work for me, instead `ArialMT` and `Times` do. I don't know why this is and how one can find a list of names that do work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `extrafont` package

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, qsec)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 22))

ggsave(filename = "myfile.eps",plot)
```

Comment: Uh, how is this different than what I already have, in practice? I still get a similar error: "In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family 'Arial' not found in PostScript font database"