# extrafont and showtext: arial not possible for eps figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have the same question as [Error using Arial in .eps figure with extrafont package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863412/error-using-arial-in-eps-figure-with-extrafont-package) but the answers did not help me: I'm using ggplot2 and cowplot for creating figures. The journal, I want to publish in, wants an eps-file with arial as font. 
I used `library(extrafont)` for changing the font and `loadfonts(device='postscript')`. 
To save the figure I used `ggsave(filename='Fig2DFH.eps')` but I get an error:

> Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : family 'Arial' not included in postscript() device

According to the link above I tried to solve it with

```
library(showtext)
font.add('Arial', regular='arial.ttf', bold='arialbd.ttf', italic='ariali.ttf', bolditalic='arialbi.ttf')
```

Here I get the following error:

```
Error in .check.font.path(regular, "regular") : 
  font file not found for 'regular' type
```

I was wondering if I did something wrong or if I have to change something in the names as I'm working with a German PC. The font.path is correct but filenames in C:Windows/Fonts/Arial are in German. I tried to change filenames in the R-command, but it did not work.

Comment: Do you find the path where the font files are installed in `font.paths()`?

Comment: Yes, I checked this:font.paths()
[1] "C:\\Windows\\Fonts"

Comment: Is the name `arial.ttf` correct?

Comment: How can I check this? Do you mean the file names under "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial? These are for example: "Arial Standard" for regular, "Arial Fett" for bold, "Arial kursiv" for italic...

Comment: Windows usually hides the real file names of fonts. To see the file name of Arial, copy the font in `C:\Windows\Fonts` and paste it to a different location, and then in the destination folder it will be an ordinary file.

Comment: Thank you, yixuan. I already solved my problem by exporting the figure as svg-file and a colleague converted it to eps with another program. But hopefully your answer will help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problems and found [this tutorial](https://github.com/wch/extrafont) very helpful. For me it worked for using Arial in an EPS device.

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
font_import() # takes a few minutes
loadfonts(device="postscript")
postscript("test_fonts.eps", width=2000, height=2000, family="Arial")
plot(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), xlab="x in Arial", ylab="y in Arial", main="a title")
dev.off()
```

This is using base plotting functionalities, you can try whether it also works for ggplot.