# using R package extrafont is generating error "font width unknown for character 0x48"

Tags: r, fonts

```
library(extrafont)
setEPS()
postscript("demo.eps", width=3.3, height=3.3, onefile=FALSE, horizontal=FALSE,      paper = "special", family = "Times New Roman")
plot(rnorm(100), main="Hey Some Data")
dev.off()
```

I have extrafont package installed and also imported fonts and loaded the fonts for postscript device. Everything was ok. But when postscript device was started with a specific font and the plot command was given it started throwing a list of error messages which basically says "font width unknown for character 0x53" etc. I embedded the font also in the graph with extrafont command embed_fonts(). It produced a plot, but no font changes were made. But when I used cairo_ps device, it worked perfectly fine. Why is it not working with postscript device? Any help?

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with the pdf device using "Arial". I have run fontimport and loaded the fonts (`extrafont::font_import()`) after which I have imported fonts to the pdf device (`extrafont::loadfonts(device = "pdf")`). It could relate to an open issue with extrafont? https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/34 . Using cairopdf it also worked fine for me.

Comment: Try to use `cairo_ps` instead of `postscript`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using

Answer (score 2):

Use "ArialMT" instead of "Arial" and "Times" instead of "Times New Roman", that worked for me with R 3.6.1 and ggplot in Windows 10.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465167/10125052